# MongoDB: How to create a collection ordered by 2 fields

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I want to create a collection:

```
var ethTransactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  blockNumber: Number,
  transactionIndex: Number,
  from: String,
  to: String,
  data: String
});
```

I need to get ordered results by blockNumber, transactionIndex: when 2 items have the same blockNumber the transactionIndex will define the order.

I have an indexes:

```
ethTransactionSchema.index({ blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 }, { unique: true });
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from: 1 });
```

When I execute the query:

```
EthTransaction.find({ from: 'address' }).sort({ blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 }).limit(20)
```

and another query:

```
EthTransaction.find(
{
     $and: [
     {
         $or: [ { from: 'address1' }, { to: 'address2' } ]
     }, 
     {
         $or: [{ blockNumber: { $gt: lastBlockGot } }, { $and: [{ blockNumber: lastBlockGot }, { transactionIndex: { $gt: lastIndexGot } }] }]
     }]
 }
 ).sort({ blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 }).limit(20)
```

I works perfect but too slow. I wonder how do I insert the fields ordered by blockNumber, transactionIndex so I can retrieve the results without the sort clause.

Comment: *I  wonder how do I insert the fields ordered by blockNumber, transactionIndex so I can retrieve the results without the sort clause.* - You can't. There is no insertion order to mongo. If you want it sorted, you need to use `.sort()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query take the index "from", and then sort in memory by blockNumber and transactionIndex.
You have to create an index made of the three field.

```
ethTransactionSchema.index({ from:1, blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 });
```

Edit:
generally if your queries are too slow you have to take a look at the explain() command. In the mongoshell execute the command

```
EthTransaction.find({ from: 'address' }).sort({ blockNumber: 1, transactionIndex: 1 }).explain()
```

Generally add`expain()` at the end of your queries to get more information on how the data are getting recovered. Also take a look  at the official documentation for [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain)

Comment: Isn't possible to insert fields ordered by {blockNumber, transactionIndex}?

Comment: If you take all results,then sort by blockNumber and transactionIndex, and finally filter by 'from' you can use the first index you have created, but the speed depends on the cardinality of the 2 index. If you can't create a new index inspect with describe which solution is optimal for your schema.

Comment: I can create a new index but the real collection isn't exactly like that (has a to field also) and there is another query which has a $or: [{ blockNumber: { $lt: lastBlockGot } }, { $and: [{ blockNumber: lastBlockGot }, { transactionIndex: { $lt: lastIndexGot } }] }] to page results.

Comment: The docs might be a helpful read: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Comment: Although, it wasn't the solution I was looking for, adding the new indexes did the trick. Thank you.